# Two tables and join and left join together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **users** table and **user_followings** table. The tables have the basic structure:

```
users: id, name, email
users_followings: following_user_id, follower_user_id
```

- follower_user_id is someone who is following some other person.
- following_user_id is someone who is being followed by some other
  person

I want that one can click on a particular user to see all the information like who are following him/her and who are the people that he/she is follwing.

```
SELECT 
      users.id, 
      users.name, 
      users.email 
                 from users
                 JOIN user_followings ON 
                                      user_followings.follower_user_id = users.id
                 WHERE user_followings.following_user_id = 1
```

This query basically joins two table and fetches desired result.

Now suppose a user named 'A' is logged in and he is looking at user X's profile. There are many people who have followed user X.

Let's say John, Mike, Rusev, Jack etc

How can write a query that tells whether logged in User 'A' is following John, Mike, Rusev, Jack etc or not along with the query that is above there.

So user A should be able to know whether he is following John, Mike, Rusev, Jack etc or not

Comment: It is hard to follow when you describe the data. Show the table structure, provide sample data, and provide a sample output.

Comment: I agree with @dfundako - clear it up please.

Comment: I agree with @disf.asia

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that OP wants to see what users are following the current user (A) that also follows the user A is viewing (X)

In my example A is id = 1 and X is id = 6

```
SELECT fu.id, fu.name, fu.email
FROM users u
JOIN users_followings f ON f.userId = u.id
JOIN users fu on fu.id = f.follower
WHERE f.userId = 1 
AND f.follower IN (SELECT follower 
                   FROM users_followings 
                   WHERE userId = 6)
```

I changed follower_user_id to follower and following_user_id to userId to not confuse myself

Answer (score 0):

Supposed the user with id=1 is viewing the details of the user with id=2 and you want to the user with id=1 to know if the followings or followers of user with id=2 are related with user with id=1 in any way. Try this:

```
SELECT C.*, 
(SELECT 1 FROM user_followings D WHERE D.following_user_id=1 AND 
  C.id=D.follower_user_id LIMIT 1) flwx_viewing_user,
(SELECT 1 FROM user_followings E WHERE E.follower_user_id=1 AND  
  C.id=E.following_user_id LIMIT 1) viewing_user_flwx
FROM
(SELECT A.id, A.name, A.email, 'following' relation 
FROM users 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 
             FROM user_followings B 
             WHERE B.following_user_id=2)
UNION ALL
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.email, 'followers' relation 
FROM users 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 
             FROM user_followings B 
             WHERE B.follower_user_id=2)) C;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it right but given ID=1 for A and ID=5 for X.
This query returns for every user that follows X the info if it is followed by A

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN exists(
      SELECT *
      FROM following AFOLLOW
      WHERE AFOLLOW.follower_user_id = 1
            AND XFOLLOWED.follower_user_id = AFOLLOW.following_user_id)
    THEN 'FOLLOWING'
  ELSE 'NOTFOLLOWING' END
FROM following XFOLLOWED
WHERE following_user_id = 5
      AND follower_user_id <> 1;
```